# Узнать, где реально исполняются js-файлы

Tags: javascript, cms

Есть большая CMSка. В одном из файлов идет подключение кучи JS-ников. 
Есть ли простой способ (Firebug, js-alert etc.), позволяющий определить, на каких страницах данные файлы используются, а на каких просто подключаются?

Немалая сложность в том, что, например, `$(document).ready(function()...` в любом случае будет вызван, но меня интересует лишь исполнение функций внутри.

Итог решения: удалить подключение JS во время общей инициализации, вставив туда, где это действительно необходимо.

Решения, которые мне кажутся слишком долгими:

1. Выводить список событий, попытавшись их распарсить в JSниках. Если совпадение найдено, выводить Alert.
2. Тупо просмотреть весь код. X[
3. Методом тыка.

Comment: По-моему, вам просто профайлер нужен. К примеру, в хроме в инструментах разработчика есть вкладка `Profiles`. Открываете ее, нажимаете `Start`, обновляете страницу, `Stop` и получаете список всех вызванных функций, их частоту и длительность выполнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug, поставить брейкпоинты в строках, которые будут для вас показателем того, что исполняется скрипт не зря (кликнуть левее номера строки). Посмотреть, дойдёт ли дело до одного из таких мест.

Всего не предусмотреть: вдруг, какой-то из скриптов слушает какое-то неочевидное событие, и только тогда «надобится»? Придётся, скорее всего, немного въехать в код, ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: Вот как раз со слушанием событий и проблемы. См выше. Брейкпоинты будут отловлены только если функция **исполнится**, а не где она **МОЖЕТ** исполниться.
Въезжать в код несколько затруднительно, так как очень много из JS генерится в PHP. 

*Упс, кажись, я спалил что за CMS:)*

Comment: раз там засветился jQuery, может, пригодится примочка для отлова всех слушателей/событий: [listHandlers](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/debug-jquery-events-with-listhandlers/)